# Сборка программы для запуска MVS

Tags: visual-studio

Создан проект в Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.
Запускаем - работает, всё открывается, ага.
Теоретически .exe файл должен создаться где-то в недрах папки с проектом.
Либо Debug, либо Release - это понятно.
Но файла приложения нет нигде. Вообще. Совсем.
Что я делаю не так? Как скомпилировать программу, чтобы этот зловещий экзешник таки появился и его, вместе с нужными ему файлами, можно было запустить на другом компьютере?

Answer (score 1):

1. Выберите **Build -> Build Solution**
2. Откройте **Output**.
3. Выберите в нём **Show output from: Build**
4. Последняя строка должна содержать путь до скомпилированного exe файла вроде этого: **ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj -> D:\dev\SandBox\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe**

Comment: Я вас обманул. Для проекта типа "Консольное приложение", это, конечно, работает. Экзешник создаётся. Но я создаю приложение на основе шаблона Javascript Web App Template. И вот там у меня и загвоздка. При отладке - запускается некое приложение, работает. А вот скомпилировать его не получается.

Comment: Я не пробовал пользоваться этим типом проекта, но я думаю что запуск происходит на сервере IIS. Смотрите где ваш сервер хранит файлы и ищите там.